# Qt Application use icon from user icon theme in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt

When I set icons for my Qt application I can provide *.png files and use `QIcon("icon.png")`, However, I want to use standard icons that were provided by the distribution and configured by the user. e.g. those from `/usr/share/icons/`. So that it respects the system's icon theme.

What method should I use to make the Qt application use the system's icon theme?

Comment: See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#fromTheme

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you very much. Do you consider writing it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, freedesktop.org has an [Icon Theme Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html) document that defines the notion of icon theme and defines an algorithm to search for specific icons. Qt follows this spec in its implementation, and as mentioned by [@eyllanesc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6622587/eyllanesc) `QIcon::fromTheme()` static method can be used to lookup needed icons.

Another relevant document, by the way, is [Icon Naming Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html), which defines some well-known names for most often used icons.